# Failed to execute 'createObjectStore' on 'IDBDatabase'

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

why do I have a error ?

My code:

```
var idb = window.indexedDB ||      // Use the standard DB API
          window.mozIndexedDB ||   // Or Firefox's early version of it
          window.webkitIndexedDB;  // Or Chrome's early version

var IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction;
var IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange;

var dbName='nameDb';

var idbRequest=idb.open(dbName,'4.67' /*,dbDescription  */);

idbRequest.onsuccess=function (e) {
    debugger

    var db=e.target.result; 

    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('chat')){
        co=db.createObjectStore('chat',{'id':100});
    };

    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('iam')){
        co1=db.createObjectStore('iam');
    }; 
};

idbRequest.onerror = function (e) {
    debugger
};
```

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'createObjectStore' on 'IDBDatabase': The database is not running a version change transaction. index.html:37
>   idbRequest.onsuccess

Comment: "Що це за" - what does it mean? :D

Comment: I understand all your comments expect this :-)

Answer (score 55):

You can't create an `objectStore` in an `onsuccess` method. You can only do this in a `upgradeneeded` event.

Quote from docs:

> When you create a new database or increase the version number of an existing database (by specifying a higher version number than you did previously, when Opening a database), the `onupgradeneeded` event will be triggered. In the handler for this event, you should create the object stores needed for this version of the database

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB).

Comment: What if populating data failed in onupgradeneeded?

Comment: So should I do data verification in onsuccess, if the data is not valid, then open the db with a higher version to trigger the onupgradeneeded again?

Comment: user1663023, consider 'db version' as set of tables/fields. And you can change this set in onupgradeneeded event only.

Comment: You can read/write data in onsuccess event as well in onupgradeneeded.

Comment: Good to me.
```open.onupgradeneeded = () => { open.result.createObjectStore('STORE_NAME') }```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try creating your objectStore on onupgradeneeded event:

request.onupgradeneeded = (event: any) => {
      const db = event.target.result;
      if(!db.objectStoreNames.contains(this.currentObjectStore)){
        db.createObjectStore(this.currentObjectStore);
      }
    };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).